# SFINAE : Delete a function with the same prototype

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, sfinae, template-function

I wonder what is the difference between this code that works :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> using is_ref = std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>;
template<typename T> using is_not_ref = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>;

template<typename T, is_ref<T> = true>
void foo(T&&) {
    std::cout << "ref" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, is_not_ref<T> = true>
void foo(T&&) {
    std::cout << "not ref" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    foo(a);
    foo(5);
}
```

and this one that does not work :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> using is_ref = std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>;
template<typename T> using is_not_ref = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>;

template<typename T, typename = is_ref<T>>
void foo(T&&) {
    std::cout << "ref" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename = is_not_ref<T>>
void foo(T&&) {
    std::cout << "not ref" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    foo(a);
    foo(5);
}
```

What is the true difference between `typename = is_ref<T>` and `is_ref<T> = true` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you remove the default template arguments, it'll become clear what the difference is. Function declarations cannot differ in *just* their defaults. This is ill-formed:

```
void foo(int i = 4);
void foo(int i = 5);
```

And likewise this is ill-formed:

```
template <typename T=int> void foo();
template <typename T=double> void foo();
```

---

With that in mind, your first case:

```
template<typename T, is_ref<T>>
void foo(T&&);

template<typename T, is_not_ref<T>>
void foo(T&&);
```

The two declarations here are unique because the second template parameter differs between the two declarations. The first has a non-type template parameter whose type is `std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>` and the second has a non-type template parameter whose type is `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference_v<T>, bool>`. Those are different types.

Whereas, your second case:

```
template<typename T, typename>
void foo(T&&);

template<typename T, typename>
void foo(T&&)
```

This is clearly the same signature - but we've just duplicated it. This is ill-formed.

---

See also [cppreference's explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes).

Comment: Absolutely logic... Which one do you advice to use to be the most explicit? Using `typename =` in all cases when it works, and the other one when you need to. Or use the `enable_if<bool> =` everytime