# Why this SFINAE fails?

Tags: c++, sfinae

```
struct BLA
{

};


template<typename T>
class DUMMY
{
public:
    DUMMY() = default;

    template<typename U = T, typename = void>
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::cout << std::is_same<U, BLA>::value << "\n";
        std::cout << "someFunction() - DEFAULT\n";
    }

    template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, void>::type>
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "someFunction()\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    DUMMY<BLA> dummy;

    dummy.someFunction();
}
```

Why is this SFINAE code calling someFunction() that displays "someFunction() - DEFAULT"? It should call the other one. It is clear that std::is_same::value is true.

Comment: what kind of compiler? on last gcc work fine https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/uGHn5t

Comment: VS2019, cl.exe, version 19.24.28315

Comment: @ProXicT, even if I add the same enable_if to the first method, only with `!` in front of is_same, everything is the same. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing as new answer because it doesn't fit to comment. For addition to @Jarod42.

It seems you assumed that

`template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, void>::type>`

substitutes to

`template<typename U = T, typename = void>`

but it doesn't. It substitutes to

`template<typename U = T, void>`.

So, you should declare it as

`template<typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, void>::type>`.

Because  the `typename` you used is for specifying the type is dependant, not for the template parameter declaration. But either won't work as you expected anyway. One silently removes the ill-formed, other one results in multiple declaration of the same function.

**After your comment, i try to explain more detailed.**

```
template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, void>::type>
void someFunction()
{
    std::cout << "someFunction()\n";
}
```

If `T == BLA`, `U` becomes `BLA` and it makes `std::is_same< U , BLA>::value` `true`. So the result looks like this

`template<typename U = BLA, void>`

If `T == NotBlaType`, `U` becomes `NotBlaType` and it makes `std::is_same<U,BLA>::value` `false`. The result is substition failure, `std::enable_if<false,void>` has no `type`.

But in both case, the function is not declared. Because `void` cannot be allowed as [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).

But if we change `void` to `int`, then it is allowed. That's why @Jarod42 suggests `int`.

`template<void>` is not legal.

But `template<int = 2>` is legal.

After making the declaration is valid, you should toggle declarations of functions conditionally (because both functions have same signature so causes to multiple declaration). That's why both functions in the @Jarod42's answer have `std::enable_if` which evalutes negate of each other.

Comment: Still, I don't see how the version with 'int' makes any difference? We replaced 'void' type with 'int'. The question still stands, what is so special about 'int' and why do you need that default value for it?

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry, missed that, fixed

Answer (score 2):

`template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, void>::type>`
would result (with correct substitution) in `template<typename U = T, void>` which is invalid.

You might change to

`template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, int>::type = 0>`

but then, both function would be viable, and so ambiguous.

So, you might finally do

```
    template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, int>::type = 0>
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::cout << std::is_same<U, BLA>::value << "\n";
        std::cout << "someFunction() - DEFAULT\n";
    }

    template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value, int>::type = 0>
    void someFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "someFunction()\n";
    }
```

In C++17, simpler to do

```
    void someFunction()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<U, BLA>::value) {
            std::cout << "someFunction()\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << std::is_same<U, BLA>::value << "\n";
            std::cout << "someFunction() - DEFAULT\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain that utterly weird 'int'?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440663/4950448 this answer :)

Comment: @Antoine, there is no any difference. void is replaced with int and then is works out of nowhere. Why is int so important in SFINAE? What kind of magic is behind that?

Comment: That "results"  in `template<typename U = T, int = 0>`, you might use other type/value. other more fragile way (can be hijacked, doesn't support overload) is `typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, BLA>::value>::type` (which results is `typename = void`).

Comment: Just read the link I sent you, you'll understand. Prototypes are the same. In the second case prototypes are differents.
Function with same prototypes are not allowed in C++.